# Doubt on Transmittance

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, optical-materials

I have a thin film deposited on a glass substrate, when I measure transmittance (T) of it ,should I use glass or air as the reference glass or air? and why?

Regarding these points:
for bare glass $T=88 \%$
for thin film deposited on glass $T= 95 \% $ ,with glass reference

Answer (score 2):

The glass carrier has a transmission less than 100% because light is reflected at the air/glass interface then again at the glass/air interface:

[image: Glass only]

I'm a bit surprised the transmission is as low as 88% and my recollection is that with normal glass between 5 - 10% of the light is reflected so the transmission should be in the low 90s. However it depends on what glass you're using and the geometry and 88% isn't miles off.

Anyhow, suppose for the sake of argument your film doesn't absorb any light, it will still cause reflections:

[image: Glass + film]

So the transmission of the glass plus film would be slightly different to just glass even when the film doesn't absorb at all.

However, if the film is strongly absorbing the effect of the reflectivity change is probably negligable. In that case comparing your glass + film against just glass will give a fairly accurate measurement of the absorption by the film. So do your measurements using an identical glass substrate as the reference.

Notes: this assumes the glass doesn't absorb the light - just reflect it - which it a fair assumption at visible wavelengths but not true at UV or IR wavelengths. It also assumes you're not using coherent light (i.e. a laser) otherwise there will be strong interference effects as well.

Comment: well fellows ,we all agreed to use glass as reference for measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, what you want to find out.

I would guess that you want to know the transmittance of just your film. Therefore, a reference measurement will be required to separate absorption from your carrier glass from the one of your film.

Now, some absorption features could be overlaying. Therefore the carrier glass might obscure some features of the film. To study that, you will need a reference measurement with just air, which shows you the absorption of the glass. This in turn tells you, if the carrier material is even suitable for the measurement. Imagine, it could show a very broad absorption, which completely hides additional absorption due to the film.

Comment: i agree with you in first part ,but the problem is if carrier glass has T=88% (which means it absorbs some light),how come the film on glass (with glass reference) ruslts in higher transmittance (95%) than bare glass?

Comment: Each interface reflects some fraction of the incident light. If the film thickness corresponds to a quarter of the wavelength (in the material) of your light, then it acts like an anti-reflective coating. Your net transmission can then be higher than without the film. Another possible explanation would be, if the film shows some luminescence in the relevant range. For example, if probe it with white light, but your detector is mostly sensitive to red and your film happens to luminesce in the red.